# ASP.NET 4.7 Forms Authentication Failure, Ticket supplied was invalid

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

We are trying to change from TLS 1.0/1.1 to 1.2. The only protocol running is 1.2 and the .net and sql has been changed to support 1.2. It started giving us this error immediately when trying to log in.

> Event code: 4005 Event message: Forms authentication failed for the
>   request. Reason: The ticket supplied was invalid.  Event time:
>   6/1/2018 9:27:58 AM Event time (UTC): 6/1/2018 1:27:58 PM Event ID:
>   ed7b05ef18c84be1b02ae683df1b6e79 Event sequence: 2 Event occurrence: 1
>   Event detail code: 50201

This is in my web.config

```
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Login/MainLoginPage.aspx" defaultUrl="/default.aspx" name="LoginAuthCookie" timeout="525600" />
    </authentication>
  <location path="Mobile/Customers/CustomerList.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Mobile/Customers/JDE/NoCust.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="login/mainloginpage.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <!--<pages validateRequest="false" />-->
      <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Applications">
    <system.web>
      <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Our testing page still works but our production does not, they have the same web.config pages.

My question is does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it? I have read up a few of the threads on this website, but they haven't been any help. Let me know if you need more information and thank you in advance for your responses.

Comment: There could be a number of reasons why this is happening.  On the production machine, is this in a root or folder off the root?  The root web.config, if exists, could be in conflict (happened to me once).  Does the machine.config on production match the test machine?  Anything hidden in global.aspx (also ran into that once)?  Your web.config looks good to me, so I think it's external to web.config.

Comment: It's in a root folder. Also both machines have the same machine.config. Nothing sticks out to me on the Global.asax page, do you have an example of something that i should be looking for on there? @PrescottChartier

Comment: Nothing in particular, see answer below, I was thinking that maybe the security protocol was already being set to something else.  I will post what I do to support TLS1.2

Comment: okay thank you @PrescottChartier

Answer (score 0):

You could add `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType) 3072;` to Global.asax.cs.

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType) 3072;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just add `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = CType(3072, SecurityProtocolType)` in `Application_Start` of `Global.ascx.vb`. Please make sure to `Imports System.Net`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but it didn't help. It gave me the "This site can't be reached error"

Comment: It seems like you will need to install .NET Framework 4.6 or above.

Answer (score 0):

I have to support TLS1.2 as my payment processor requires it, I believe all do now.  I was dealing with an 12 year old application so I didn't want to possibly introduce issues into the overall application so I inserted one line of code into the relevant page and all is well.  That one line is:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```

This forces the `httprequest` that follows to connect using TLS1.2.  Works for me.

**NOTE:**
I upgraded the entire app (not an issue) to .NET 4.5, earlier versions do not support TLS1.2